# check if a set of dates is smaller than NOW() - mysql

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-functions

I have an "events" table and a "events_dates" table.
"events_dates" has a reference to event_id in "events" table.
I would like to build a stored function that checks if NOW() is bigger of ALL the dates in "events_dates" referred to a specific event_id.
I have written that function in order to get a tinyint(1) value (1 if true, 0 if false), but I get always false.
Moreover, I think I get lost using loops.
What would you do in my place?

I want to use that function in a bigger query and use it like:

```
SELECT e.*, ed.*
FROM events e INNER JOIN
     events_dates ed
     ON e.event_id = ed.fk_event_id
 WHERE IF (checkIfAllDatesArePassed(e.event_id),DATEDIFF(ed.event_date,NOW())<0,DATEDIFF(ed.event_date,NOW())>0)
```

Actually it is a little bit more complex, but I am sure you get what the point is :)

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the ALL keyword, e.g.

```
select *
from events
where now() > all (select event_date from events_dates where fk_event_id = event_id)
```

Supposing event_id is a parameter of your function.

I could not fathom what the checkIfAllDatesArePassed was supposed to be however.

Update from the comments:

```
drop function if exists checkIfAllDatesArePassed;
delimiter $$
create function checkIfAllDatesArePassed(event_id integer)
returns integer
language sql
begin
return select case
when now() > all (select event_date from events_dates where fk_event_id = event_id) then 1
else 0;
end;
$$
delimiter;
```

Would that do?

Comment: checkIfAllDatesArePassed  is the function I am trying to build :)  That function must return 1 if all the dates are minor than NOW() or 0 if at least one of the dates is greater than NOW().

Comment: Well do try the ALL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html keyword, after all it exists for that purpose :)

Comment: I have updated my submission. However, please check that the syntax is correct for the function. It's been a while since I've written a function in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the *events* that meet this criteria along with a flag:

```
SELECT ed.event_id,
       (max(event_date) < now()) as AllDatesPast
FROM events_dates ed
group by event_id;
```

If you want the *event* information, then join in `events`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM events e join
     events_dates ed
     on e.event_id = ed.fk_event_id
group by e.event_id
having max(event_date) < now();
```

And if you want the dates:

```
SELECT e.*, ed.*
FROM events e join
     events_dates ed
     on e.event_id = ed.fk_event_id
WHERE not exists (select 1
                  from event_dates ed2
                  where e.event_id = ed2.event_id and
                        event_date > now()
                 ) ;
```

Comment: thanks for your solutions. I just need the function to return 1 or 0. Please check my comment to @codeblur solution. Thank you